# Web part settings losing their values every day

Tags: web-part, application-pool

I have a web part custome setting, defined as below. It works fine but it seem to lose its value once a day!? Is this because the app pool is getting recycled or some such?

Is there anyway to prevent this?

```
[WebBrowsable(true),
    Personalizable(true),
    WebDisplayName("Site Root"),
    WebDescription("The site root url, so the the webpart can find the SP webservices"),
    Category("Custom Settings"),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared),
    DefaultValue("http://url/")]
    public string SiteRoot
    {
        get { return _siteroot; }
        set
        {
             _siteroot = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Someone solved the Problem. I got the same here... :<

Comment: are you using content deployment ?

Comment: can you add the declaration of _siteroot too?

Answer (score 1):

Just some suggestions:

Personalizable(true) is equivalent to Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User). Have you tried Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)?

WebPartStorageAttribute does not exist in the System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts namespace - are you using the older Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages namespace?

Comment: I added this   `Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)` and removed `WebPartStorage` but I still get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with app pool recycles.

A couple of things:

- You should not use WebPartStorage attribute when building ASP.NET based Web Parts (ie derived from the System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart). It's superseeded by the Personalizable attribute
- As SPDoctor says - Personalizable(true) is the same as as Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User) - which means that every user can personalize the property and having their own values of it
- Do you do anything with the page before the value is getting reset?
- Admins/authors can reset user personalized values to the shared value by resetting the web part
- for more info check out an old post of mine: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Web-Part-Properties-part-1-introduction.aspx

Comment: I added this   `Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)` and removed `WebPartStorage` but I still get the same behaviour. I don't think anything is being done on the page. Just seems to happen at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by removing the static declaration from the field _siteroot. Since I removed the static declaration no data get lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a very similar issue at the minute. My web part property Attributes are all kosher, but the part forgets the property settings when someone checks out the page - draft users can't see the property.

Yeah, publishing pages.